# Google Apps API - get subscription details

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I'm writing an utility to email an alert when:

1. a Google Apps domain's number of users approaches the subscription limit
2. a Google Apps domain's subscription is coming up for renewal

I found the data for point 1 in the Admin Settings API in fields called `MaximumNumberOfUsers` and `CurrentNumberOfUsers`

Unfortunately I cannot find any subscription/billing details in the APIs except in the Reseller APIs (which doesn't help me, I'm not a reseller)

This information is available in other cloud product APIs, like Office 365 etc.

Does anyone know if this information is accessible via an API?

Answer (score 0):

The [License Manager API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/licensing/) provides a way to get/update/assign licenses to users but does not provide details about subscription renewals.

There is no API function currently to retrieve the renewal date.